# How to Call Activator.CreateInstance, passing a Method as Constructor Argument?

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

How can the following be created via reflection?

```
var t = new SomeFrameworkType<string, string>(s => MyClass.MyMethod(s));
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
var typeParamOne = Type.GetType("System.String");
var typeParamTwo = Type.GetType("System.String");
var myClass= Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication.MyClass");
var myMethod = myClass.GetMethod("MyMethod");
var type = typeof(SomeFrameworkType<,>);
var typeArgs = new[] {typeParamOne, typeParamTwo };
var constructed= type.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed, myMethod);
```

The sample is the way it is as most of the required info will not be known and will be supplied as parameters.

Now, the "instance" assignation will throw an exception. How can I appropriately pass through to the constructor?

Also, how would I cast the result to SomeFramework so I can work with it when I don't know the type parameters?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not just pass a method, you're passing an anonymous method as a delegate. You need to construct that delegate.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. That's what I'm asking. How do I construct that to pass as an argument? I don't want to invoke the method (that happens at some later point).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `SomeFrameworkType<,>` definition is something like the following:

```
class SomeFrameworkType<T1, T2> { 
  public SomeFrameworkType(Func<T1, T2> func) {}
}
```

and the generic type parameters for `T1` and `T2` are `System.String` (*like in OP's example*), then it can be instantiated via reflection using the following codes:

```
var typeParamOne = typeof (string);
var typeParamTwo = typeof(string);
var myClass = typeof(ConsoleApplication.MyClass);
var myMethod = myClass.GetMethod("MyMethod");
var type = typeof(SomeFrameworkType<,>);
var typeArgs = new[] { typeParamOne, typeParamTwo };
var constructed = type.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

// construct the delegate
var ctrArgs = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
var dlgate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ctrArgs, myMethod);

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed, dlgate);
```

*AFAIK*, we need to know at least the generic type parameters for casting the resulting `object` to `SomeFrameworkType<,>` or (as pointed by Jon G) use the non-generic base type of `SomeFrameworkType<,>` if any.

```
var casted = instance as SomeFrameworkType<string, string>;
```

Comment: I had to modify CreateDelegate to take the constructed instance of myClass (also using Activator.CreateInstance) and I was in business, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a MethodInfo as the constructor parameter, when the constructor expects a delegate which is maybe Action or Func or similar.

Can you change SomeFrameworkType to take MethodInfo in its constructor?

Otherwise you could, instead of myMethod in the final line, use something like s => myMethod.Invoke(s)

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed, s => myMethod.Invoke(s));
```

Assuming the delegate signature of the constructor expects a return type of object, this should work.

Re: casting the result, if you want to use the object in a strongly typed manner, you need to cast it to a type that you know at compile time. If SomeFrameworkType<,> has a non-generic base type then you could as- or bracket-cast to that type and use the resulting object.

Comment: Hi, sorry, that will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the lambda as a parameter, although you will have to qualify it with some delegate type (`System.Action`, `System.Func` or similar)

This code works for me:

```
var typeParamOne = typeof(string);
var typeParamTwo = typeof(string);

// we could do new Action<string>(s => MyClass.MyMethod(s)); 
// but why bother when the method signature matches already
var callbackMethod = new Action<string>(MyClass.MyMethod);

var type = typeof(SomeFrameworkType<,>);
var constructed = type.MakeGenericType(typeParamOne, typeParamTwo);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed, callbackMethod);

var castedInstance = (SomeFrameworkType<string, string>)instance;
castedInstance.CallTheCallback();
```

In fact, we don't need `Activator.CreateInstance` at all - we can just get the specific constructor we want, and then invoke it. This would be faster if we were creating many instances of the same type of object. Example:

```
var type = typeof(SomeFrameworkType<,>);
var constructed = type.MakeGenericType(typeParamOne, typeParamTwo);
var constructor = constructed.GetConstructor(new[]{ typeof(Action<string>) });
var instance = constructor.Invoke(new object[] { callbackMethod });
```

What if you want to invoke methods on `instance` without casting it? Just use `InvokeMember`, like this

```
constructed.InvokeMember(
    "CallTheCallback", 
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, 
    null, 
    instance, 
    null);
```

If you don't know what kind of callback method you'll need, then it seems like there will be a problem, because you always want to call `MyClass.MyMethod`, which has a fixed known type. for example: if the constructor to `SomeFrameworkType<int, int>` requires you to also pass a delegate of type `Action<int>`, then this doesn't line up with `MyClass.MyMethod` which may take a string parameter. 
You'd need to do one of the following:
- create some extra wrapper methods which would convert the int to a string (or similar), and then pass those wrapper methods when creating the `instance`
- create a bunch of overloads of `MyClass.MyMethod` with different parameter types, and have some logic to select the correct one
- make `MyClass.MyMethod` generic, and do something like this:

```
// create the delegate type so we can find the appropriate constructor
var delegateType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(typeParamOne);

// work out concrete type for calling the generic MyMethod
var myMethodType = typeof(MyClass)
    .GetMethod("MyMethod")
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeParamOne);

// create an instance of the delegate type wrapping MyMethod so we can pass it to the constructor
var delegateInstance = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, myMethodType);

var type = typeof(SomeFrameworkType<,>);
var constructed = type.MakeGenericType(typeParamOne, typeParamTwo);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed, delegateInstance);
```

Comment: I am trying to follow your example here, but I cant get it to work, because things like your definition of "CallTheCallback() is not declared here, so it makes it difficult to follow.

Can you possibly add the full code here, and not assume I know whats the rest will look like. thanks

Comment: @GerriePretorius the example is deliberately not a full example, it's designed to show a set of things that you might do, rather than be a perfect copy/pastable example. Basically: Now you konw about MakeGenericMethod, GetConstructor and Invoke, you can put them together yourself to form your own specific solution